# Find out if an element was rerendered

Tags: ember.js

I dynamically add `content` and I'd like to get informed about DOM changes in my view, e.g. for measuring the dimension after new content has been added.

I have already tried observing `controller.isLoaded`, but that happens too early. Right now, I'm using a DOM observer plugin for jQuery.

Is there something like `didRerenderElement`?

Comment: are you by any chance trying to check whether the view "is dirty" ?

Comment: Nope, does Ember set `View.isDirty` to true when its DOM changes?

Comment: No, I don't think so, but I was gonna say that in theory you could in implement this with [`rerender`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method_rerender), but I'm not sure how you're gonna handle model properties which don't fire changes in DOM. I haven't looking very much into it, but that might be a possible option allied with `beginPropertyChanges` or `propertyDidChange`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `afterRender` on my views does the job. Thank you, @Unspecified!

Answer (score 0):

There is this `didInsertElement` method which will be executed when the view is inserted into the DOM,

Usage:

```
App.myView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    alert("View is inserted into the DOM");
  }
})
```

Check if this helps...

Comment: `didInsertElement` gets fired when the DOM element was inserted. But I need something that informs me when it was manipulated...

Comment: I think there is a didRerender method, check Ember library once

Comment: I already tried to find something in the source code, but I was unable to find anything that looks like an event. Do you have some more information?

Comment: Sorry that is willRereder   From the sourcecode: /**
    Called when the view is about to rerender, but before anything has
    been torn down. This is a good opportunity to tear down any manual
    observers you have installed based on the DOM state
  */

Comment: Also there is a afterRender: Ember.K, method no comments available for that one, check this one too